# How to transform a data frame into a ts object on R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to transform my data frame into a time series object.
I've tried to use the function ts:

```
testTS<- ts(daily2018$UI,start=as.Date(daily2018$Date),frequency=365.25)
```

But my dates are not right, appearing to start at 15381.99 86310746

When I use the function xts:

```
ts<-xts(daily2018$UI,daily2018$Date)
```

it works, but when I apply decompose(), it gives me an error, saying that "The time series doesn't have a period, or has less than 2"
The dataset has daily measures from 2012 to 2018.

```
structure(list(Dia = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18), Mes = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), Ano = c(2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012), UI = c(18.0647497177124, 51.0355095863342, 47.5402774810791, 
340.893737792969, 247.539836883545, 399.510726928711, 122.39359664917, 
98.836296081543, 35.0952081680298, 50.6278982162476, 87.2319049835205, 
77.6166572570801, 112.672420501709, 2.67568874359131, -392.484573364258, 
618.681500434875, 692.416625976562, 236.788291931152, 51.255313873291, 
71.8802337646484, 345.232437133789, 236.85432434082, -0.00471636652946472, 
-27.9389114379883, 146.920881986618, 341.540222167969, 1208.46826171875, 
454.171142578125, 94.2786865234375, -23.250904083252, 6.60693836212158, 
11.3990550041199, 461.585052490234, 110.249738693237, 282.145706176758, 
30.0083067417145, 922.615142822266, 665.348541259766, 280.90966796875, 
129.148958206177, 97.8483505249023, 151.280666351318, 41.1154479980469, 
462.513458251953, 223.375587463379, 243.899364471436, 91.236083984375, 
-33.4530096054077, 419.289459228516, 216.38060760498, 223.88525390625, 
42.9771499633789, 63.462251663208, 135.543815612793, 103.11067199707, 
-2.97302103042603, 50.1539402008057, 31.7654695510864, 4.74521112442017, 
116.475090026855, -31.0308532714844, 95.1957511901855, -74.0424919128418, 
74.0312874317169, 370.580841064453, 439.345306396484, 288.222801208496, 
245.310737609863, 163.978561401367, -43.6043725013733, 90.422176361084, 
13.5707854032516, 35.8152360916138, -251.285369873047, -396.40592956543, 
27.4398317337036, 119.581299781799, 374.314788818359, 895.551239013672, 
583.116119384766, 83.0863494873047, -162.666477203369, -326.430221557617, 
-219.034694671631, 246.566764831543, 142.276351928711, 167.783622741699, 
116.547183990479, -962.846618652344, -199.737373352051, 581.776489257812, 
127.202213287354, 243.02904510498, 546.869003295898, 322.698364257812, 
416.055419921875, -35.2042512893677, 4.76407432556152, 59.2325496673584, 
109.642734527588, 39.2587299346924, 70.3620586395264, 3161.94677734375, 
1006.70434570312, 2140.01275634766, 2786.77355957031, 1705.16961669922, 
944.830413818359, 655.952301025391, 338.197479248047, 63.7034378051758, 
519.655364990234, 658.758819580078, 443.135345458984, 365.920120239258, 
-533.251229286194, 514.586601257324, 67.87255859375, -295.31233215332, 
175.399646759033, 27.4736328125, -3460.8505859375, -2083.35198974609, 
-1276.77111816406, -203.34831237793, 121.706581115723, -1469.41851806641, 
-224.111042022705, 191.504776000977, 172.109447479248, 26.7028465270996, 
113.872447013855, 115.648100852966, 365.883389472961, 2044.16656494141, 
-32.7207946777344, 24.2001395225525, 1416.10055541992, -49.864501953125, 
953.696166992188, 1353.91192626953, 331.314163208008, 755.130172729492, 
504.707885742188, 1100.87829589844, 410.127822875977, 1059.75042724609, 
1814.80114746094, 732.802597045898, 2145.48461914062, 2912.95367431641, 
210.142471313477, 39.4968557357788, 380.054672241211, 278.151397705078, 
1334.32025146484, 681.097854614258, -69.2400665283203, 567.077270507812, 
624.232055664062, 391.584182739258, 586.699615478516, 1279.32067871094, 
3932.2900390625, 789.148895263672, 474.529556274414, 316.368942260742, 
589.92162322998, 107.363967418671, 3477.34375, 241.996397972107, 
350.299514770508, 3326.77624511719, 2569.17126464844, 4582.50708007812, 
1923.22076416016, -61.1435556411743, -85.2687129974365, 217.463203430176, 
517.184478759766, 172.391616821289, 1056.78869628906, 2622.95007324219, 
2552.87609863281, 1118.66555786133, 1658.28143310547, 1830.66302490234, 
1645.97857666016, 874.851470947266, 1195.69207763672, 771.39143371582, 
1265.49255371094, 1729.88415527344, 4629.59558105469, 3249.35119628906, 
2862.19885253906, 2368.9833984375, 380.631881713867, 276.73908996582, 
5071.85693359375), Date = structure(c(1325376000, 1325462400, 
1325548800, 1325635200, 1325721600, 1325808000, 1325894400, 1325980800, 
1326067200, 1326153600, 1326240000, 1326326400, 1326412800, 1326499200, 
1326585600, 1326672000, 1326758400, 1326844800, 1326931200, 1327017600, 
1327104000, 1327190400, 1327276800, 1327363200, 1327449600, 1327536000, 
1327622400, 1327708800, 1327795200, 1327881600, 1327968000, 1328054400, 
1328140800, 1328227200, 1328313600, 1328400000, 1328486400, 1328572800, 
1328659200, 1328745600, 1328832000, 1328918400, 1329004800, 1329091200, 
1329177600, 1329264000, 1329350400, 1329436800, 1329523200, 1329609600, 
1329696000, 1329782400, 1329868800, 1329955200, 1330041600, 1330128000, 
1330214400, 1330300800, 1330387200, 1330473600, 1330560000, 1330646400, 
1330732800, 1330819200, 1330905600, 1330992000, 1331078400, 1331164800, 
1331251200, 1331337600, 1331424000, 1331510400, 1331596800, 1331683200, 
1331769600, 1331856000, 1331942400, 1332028800, 1332115200, 1332201600, 
1332288000, 1332374400, 1332460800, 1332547200, 1332633600, 1332720000, 
1332806400, 1332892800, 1332979200, 1333065600, 1333152000, 1333238400, 
1333324800, 1333411200, 1333497600, 1333584000, 1333670400, 1333756800, 
1333843200, 1333929600, 1334016000, 1334102400, 1334188800, 1334275200, 
1334361600, 1334448000, 1334534400, 1334620800, 1334707200, 1334793600, 
1334880000, 1334966400, 1335052800, 1335139200, 1335225600, 1335312000, 
1335398400, 1335484800, 1335571200, 1335657600, 1335744000, 1335830400, 
1335916800, 1336003200, 1336089600, 1336176000, 1336262400, 1336348800, 
1336435200, 1336521600, 1336608000, 1336694400, 1336780800, 1336867200, 
1336953600, 1337040000, 1337126400, 1337212800, 1337299200, 1337385600, 
1337472000, 1337558400, 1337644800, 1337731200, 1337817600, 1337904000, 
1337990400, 1338076800, 1338163200, 1338249600, 1338336000, 1338422400, 
1338508800, 1338595200, 1338681600, 1338768000, 1338854400, 1338940800, 
1339027200, 1339113600, 1339200000, 1339286400, 1339372800, 1339459200, 
1339545600, 1339632000, 1339718400, 1339804800, 1339891200, 1339977600, 
1340064000, 1340150400, 1340236800, 1340323200, 1340409600, 1340496000, 
1340582400, 1340668800, 1340755200, 1340841600, 1340928000, 1341014400, 
1341100800, 1341187200, 1341273600, 1341360000, 1341446400, 1341532800, 
1341619200, 1341705600, 1341792000, 1341878400, 1341964800, 1342051200, 
1342137600, 1342224000, 1342310400, 1342396800, 1342483200, 1342569600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `decompose` the time needs to be represented in a manner where

- a complete cycle is represented by 1 time unit
- every time unit contains the same number of points
- there are at least 2 complete cycles
- the class of the series is "ts"

thus we can't use an annual cycle since there are fewer than 2 years and we can't use a date for the time index but we could use a monthly cycle if we reduce the number of points to be the same number in each month -- we use 28 below although in this particular series we could have used 29 since the data all comes from 2012 which is a leap year.  The time index will be the month number plus 0 for day 1 of the month, 1/28 for day 2 of the month, ..., 27/28 for day 28 of the month.

```
UI <- ts(subset(daily2018, Dia <= 28), frequency = 28)[, "UI"]
d <- decompose(UI)
plot(d) # see plot at end of answer
```

Note that the series name in the question is daily2018 but it only contains data for 2012.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer! I couldn't put the entire dataset because it is too big. But how would I set the frequency for all the years? I tried: ````ts <- ts(subset(daily2018), frequency = 365,25)[, "UI"]```` but the date is still wrong

Comment: You can use  UI <- ts(subset(daily2018, as.POSIXlt(Date)$yday < 365), frequency = 365)[, "UI"]  if you want annual cycles and you have at least 2 years of data.  This will drop Dec 31st in leap years to ensure that every year has 365 days.  As mentioned in the answer ts objects can't really express dates in a nice way.